# Got Error when adding googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

when I added the last implementation which is `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1`, I Got this error:

> All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different Firebase. **First**, you're using the old version of firebase with:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

**Second**, you're using the more recent Firebase version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
```

So, you need to migrate your old Firebase. You can do that by changing the old firebase dependency with:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"
```

You must see the full step to migrate from your old Firebase on 
[Upgrade your Android app from Firebase.com](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)

Also, you need to use the same version of Firebase and Google Play Service. In the end, your dependencies will be like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: this will give me : Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1
AND also : Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.1

Comment: but it works with version 15.0.0 of both firebase and google play service . thanks

Comment: Great, glad it help you! I'll fix the answer based on your comment ;)